# How do I load a DataGrid from a single column datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I load a single column datatable from a database query.  Then I want to assign the datatable to a datagrid.  The datatable gets loaded fine but the datagrid does not load.  I do this in other code and it works fine.  I don't get why it doesn't work here.

XAML Code:

```
    <DataGrid 
        IsReadOnly="True" 
        Name="dtCIDGrid" 
        Background="#FFE8F9FF" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Height="150" 
        Margin="24,66,0,0" 
        Width="240" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger 
                        Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" 
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9DF3D6" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
private void LoadCardIssueDates(string strClientID, SqlConnection sqlConn, string strErrorLogFile)
    {
        bool blnSuccess = false;
        DataTable dtCIDData = new DataTable();


        dtCIDData.Columns.Add("Card Issue Date", typeof(string));

        blnSuccess = GetCardIssueDates(strClientID, sqlConn, dtCIDData, strErrorLogFile);
    }

private bool GetCardIssueDates(string strClientID, SqlConnection sqlConn, DataTable dtCIDData, string strErrorLogFile)
    {
        string strCardIssueDate = string.Empty;
        string[] strDatePieces = new string[3];
        DateTime dtCardIssueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900");
        bool blnSuccess = false;


        if (sqlConn != null && sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("GetCardIssueDates", sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Char, 36);

                    // set parameter values that your code will send to the SP as parameter values
                    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ClientID"].Value = strClientID;

                    using (SqlDataReader sdrData = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdrData.Read())
                        {
                            if (sdrData.IsDBNull(0))
                            {
                                strCardIssueDate = string.Empty;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dtCardIssueDate = (DateTime)sdrData["issuedate"];
                                strCardIssueDate = dtCardIssueDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                            }

                            dtCIDData.Rows.Add(strCardIssueDate);
                        }

                        dtCIDGrid.ItemsSource = dtCIDData.DefaultView;

                        sdrData.Close();
                    }

                    sqlCmd.Clone();
                    sqlCmd.Dispose();

                    blnSuccess = true;
                }

                blnSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                WriteCIDErrorLog("InsertCardIssueDate", sqlex.Message, strErrorLogFile, false);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("InsertCardIssueDate: SQL Error, " + sqlex.Message + ", has occurred.");
                blnSuccess = false;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException invex)
            {
                WriteCIDErrorLog("InsertCardIssueDate", invex.Message, strErrorLogFile, false);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("InsertCardIssueDate: Invalid Operation Error, " + invex.Message + ", has occurred.");
                blnSuccess = false;
            }
            catch (Exception exQuery)
            {
                WriteCIDErrorLog("InsertCardIssueDate", exQuery.Message, strErrorLogFile, false);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("InsertCardIssueDate: Exception Error, " + exQuery.Message + ", has occurred.");
                blnSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WriteCIDErrorLog("InsertCardIssueDate", "There is no database connection.", strErrorLogFile, false);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("InsertCardIssueDate: There is no database connection.");
        }

        return blnSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: where are you trying to assign the `DataTable` to `DataGrid` ? in code behind ?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the full code, not sure why copy paste didn't have everything

Comment: what is `dtCIDData` ? show where is it declared, Have you checked your `dtCIDData.DefaultView` has rows ?

Comment: I added the routine that creates the datatable

Comment: #Abin Mathew -- dtCIDData.DefaultView has the date and dtCIDGrid.ItemsSource has the data.  However dtCIDGrid.Columns count is 0.  It should be 1.  I'm not sure why it isn't.